# How to make ajax form with validation

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I need to make validation before sending data

My html:

```
<section id="contacts" class="section-block">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
        <p class="section-header text-center">Хотите задать вопрос?</p>
        <div class="separator center-block"></div>
            <p class="section-after-header text-center">Мы ответим не позже следующего рабочего дня</p>
            <form id="contactForm">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="InputName" id="InputName" placeholder="Ваше имя" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="email" class="form-control" name="InputEmail" id="InputEmail"  placeholder="Ваш e-mail" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" id="questioninput" class="form-control" name="InputQuestion" id="InputQuestion"  placeholder="Вопрос" />
            </div>
            <div id="success"> </div>
                <button type="submit_m" id="submit" class="btn btn-yellow center-block">Задать вопрос</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

js/jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#submit").click(function() {
        var name = $("#InputName").val();
        var email = $("#InputEmail").val();
        var text = $("#InputQuestion").val();

        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<y:base />/tmpls/hb.theme/sendemail.php",
        data: {name: name, email: email, text: text},
        success: function() {
            $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-success' style='margin-bottom: 15px;'>");
            $('#success > .alert-success').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true' style='font-size: 15px;font-family: Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;'>&times;")
            .append( "</button>");
            $('#success > .alert-success').append("Ваш запрос отправлен. Мы перезвоним вам в ближайшее время!");
            $('#success > .alert-success').append('</div>');
            $('#contactForm').trigger("reset");
        },
        error: function() {
            $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-danger'>");
            $('#success > .alert-danger').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true' style='font-size: 15px;font-family: Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;'>&times;").append( "</button>");
            $('#success > .alert-danger').append("Кажется у нас что-то поломалось. Пожалуйста, напишите нам по почте и мы вам сразу же ответим. Спасибо!");
            $('#success > .alert-danger').append('</div>');
            $('#contactForm').trigger("reset");
        },
        });
    });
});
```

php

```
<?
if((isset($_POST['name'])&&$_POST['name']!="")&&(isset($_POST['email'])&&$_POST['email']!="")){
    $to = 'asd@asd.ru';
    $subject = 'Вопрос с главной страницы';
    $val = array(
                 'name' => strip_tags(@$_POST['name']),
                 'email' => strip_tags(@$_POST['email']),
                 'text' => strip_tags(@$_POST['text'])
                 );

    $message = "Вопрос на главной странице сайта\nИмя клиента: {$val['name']}\nEmail: {$val['email']}\nВопрос: {$val['text']}";
    $headers  = "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8 \r\n"; /
    $headers .= "From: www.asd.ru <asd@asd.ru>\r\n";
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
}
?>
```

I want to use [validate.js](https://validatejs.org/) or any other code which will help me to show messages that fields are not filled or email doesn't look like email.

Problem is that if I use standard bootstrap validation (required='true') with on click event form sends even if fields are not filled. If I use on submit event it updates page (it is long page and after update it opens top of page, but not contact form with success message)

Comment: I don't see _any_ attempt on trying to validate the data in JS. You're simply just fetching the data of the inputs and sending it using ajax.

Comment: the HTML5 required attribute is not bootstraps

Comment: @MagnusEriksson because i dont understand how to connet it with validate js

Comment: @SergioAlen thanks, will know

Answer (score 0):

You need to prevent the default action of the submit button before doing anything, like this:

```
$("#submit").click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
// validation code goes here
  // return true if validation is successful and proceed to ajax
});
```